# Is there a dynamic way to retrieve url parameters needed for JSON data set?

Tags: json

For example, the available API for this Mountain Bike website: https://www.mtbproject.com/data, one can receive JSON data for mountain bike trails based on your request. But I would have to painstakingly collect all the URL parameters, it would seem, in order to create a data set for my API call that I want to make. Is there a more efficient way to do this or is this just the way it is, given a scenario such as this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library for making ajax requests.
You can set the params as an object like this:

```js
axios.get("https://www.mtbproject.com/data/get-trails", {
  params:{
   lat:40.0274,
   lon:-105.2519,
   maxDistance:10,
   key:'YOUR_KEY_HERE'
  }
}).then(console.log, e => console.log(e))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

If you dont want to apply this beautifull library into your project.You may try to use 
pure javascript `URL` interface.Keep in mind that this is not supported by IE and you may apply some polyfill for this browser to make it work.

[DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
var requestUrl = new URL('https://www.mtbproject.com/data/get-trails')
requestUrl.searchParams.set('lat', 40.0274)
requestUrl.searchParams.set('lon', -105.2519)
requestUrl.searchParams.set('maxDistance', 10)
requestUrl.searchParams.set('key', "YOUR_KEY_HERE")

console.log(requestUrl.toString())

// you can even make your own wrapper for this

function MyURL(url, params = {}){
  
  this._url = url
  this._params = params
  
  this.toString = () => {
    var url = this._url
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams()
    
    for(var key in this._params){
      searchParams.set(key, this._params[key])
    }
    var stringSearchParams = searchParams.toString().length > 0 ? '?' + searchParams.toString() : ''
    return url +  stringSearchParams
  }

}

var myUrlTest = new MyURL('https://www.mtbproject.com/data/get-trails', {param1:'test', param2: 'test2'})

console.log(myUrlTest.toString())
```

You can find quite alot of libraries for managing the queries.
For example [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string)

Anyway its good to post your code with such a question.I am wondering if i have answered your question correct, with some code it would be more straight forward i guess.

Cheers!